# cloth breaks away from armature as soon as first frame of bake begins

Tags: rigging, physics

I am trying to animate with auto rig pro with cloth physics baking on my character. However, whenever i leave off and enter into the first frame of the bake, the cloth that has the physics simulation on it breaks away from the armature and does not deform with the character as the cloth is baking. How can I animate the character and keep the cloth baking at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I did not realize that one has to set the key frames and animation data before the bake in order for it to follow. Duh, right. Its taking all of the information to bake clothing along with that includes location, rotation, and scale.

Comment: Hi, MuffinMan. Glad you got it sorted. I really do mean that. I suffer so much with similar issues, and I wouldn't wish them on my worst enemy. I wanted to let you know that I created a chatroom on this site for Auto Rig Pro users. It's my hope that what few of them there are will be able to get more answers to their questions by seeking other users out there, since almost no one seems to use it.